# getLatLong always returns false

Tags: android, exif

I'm trying to retrieve longitude and latitude values from geotagged images using android.media.ExifInterface library. However, getLatLong always returns false although the image is geotagged. This is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button galleryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.galleryButton);

    galleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);


        }

    });


}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                ExifInterface exif = new ExInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
                float[] latlong = null;
                bool result = exif.getLatLong(latlong);


            }

            break;

    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm initializing exif object with the path from returned URI and it contains path like "/external/images/media/2330". When I call getLatLong, it always returns false. I have also tried the example from [this page](https://www.codota.com/android/methods/android.media.ExifInterface/getLatLong), but still does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Galaxy S6 Edge
Android SDK Version 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getPath()` only works on a `Uri` with a `file` scheme. Yours has a `content` scheme. Plus, you are using the `ExifInterface` with the security flaws.

Add the `com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1` library to your `dependencies`.

Next, replace your `android.media.ExifInterface` import with one for `android.support.media.ExifInterface`.

Then, replace:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
```

with:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage));
```